# How to use font-awesome animated icons in Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, vuejs3

I can import fontawesome-icons in `app.js`:

```js
import {createApp} from 'vue';
import app from "../vue/app";
import {library} from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import {FontAwesomeIcon} from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import {faWrench} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faWrench);

createApp(app)
    .component('fa', FontAwesomeIcon)
    .mount("#app");
```

and use them in components like so:

```html
<fa :icon="[ 'fa', 'wrench' ]" size="2x"></fa>
```

The [font-awesome-animation npm doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome-animation) tells to use this:

```html
<i class="fa fa-wrench faa-wrench animated"></i>
```

but it doesn't seem to work in `Vue 3`.

I've tried importing `font-awesome-animation` after installing it like so:

```js
import {faaWrench} from 'font-awesome-animation';

library.add(faaWrench);
```

but it breaks the site and the console shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prefix')
```

How do I use `font-awesome-animation` in `Vue 3`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`font-awesome-animation` is just a collection of CSS animation keyframes, defined as global styles. The package does not have any exports, so don't try to import anything from it (which would just be `undefined`, leading to the error you observed when trying to add it to the icon library).

To use `font-awesome-animation` from NPM, import its CSS file like this:

```js
// main.js
import 'font-awesome-animation/css/font-awesome-animation.min.css'
```

Then append the `faa-ANIMATION_NAME` (where `ANIMATION_NAME` is one of the animations from [the library's animation list](https://www.npmjs.com/package/font-awesome-animation#user-content-animation-list)) and `animated` classes to a `<font-awesome-icon>`. For example, this markup applies the `tada` animation to the `fas-snowman` icon:

```html
<font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'snowman']" class="faa-tada animated" />
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-fontawesome-animation?file=src%2Fmain.js)